# How to reference your code in a Markdown file with no copy/pasting on local machine

Tags: markdown

When I learn some new coding concepts I like keeping good notes in markdown files along my program files .js, .py. So far, I have been copying and pasting code into my markdown file (code snippet) with my notes but copy / pasting is somewhat redundant since I already have the code and it makes more sense to reference my code in my markdown file without copy / pasting.

[GitHub has this as a feature](https://www.stevemar.net/github-code-in-readme/), but I’d like to have the same thing locally.

Comment: Markdown doesn't have this feature.

Answer (score -1):

You can use extensions like `Markdown All in One` or `Markdown Preview Enhanced`.
These extensions support features like including code blocks from external files using a relative path, which can be very handy for your use case.

To include a code snippet from a file, you would typically use syntax like:

````
```python
[!include](relative/path/to/your/main.py)
````